# Add multiple columns with one when clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a code that looks like that:

```
df.withColumn( colPath , when( col(colType) =!= S_IFLNK_name, regexp_extract(col(tempColPath) , exp = "^(.*\\/).*$", groupIdx = 1 ) )
                                   .otherwise( regexp_extract( col(tempColPath), exp = "^(.*\\/)(?:[^\\/]+\\-\\>.*)$", groupIdx = 1 ) ) )
         .withColumn( colFilename, when( col(colType) =!= S_IFLNK_name, regexp_extract(col(tempColPath), exp = "^(?:.*\\/)(.*)$", groupIdx = 1 ) )
                                   .otherwise( regexp_extract( col(tempColPath), exp = "^(?:.*\\/)([^\\/]+\\-\\>.*)$", groupIdx = 1 ) ) )
```

It's not necessary to understand that code but my goal here would be to be able to use only one when clause and add 2 columns at once.
Doing this test twice to add a column is a terrible performance issue, is it possible ?
I tried to use `match case` but you can't apply them to `Columns` values.

Answer (score 0):

From spark documentation for `withColumn`: (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumn-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-):

> Returns a new Dataset by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.

So, use a `.withColumn` for each of the new columns that you need to add.

```
yourDF
  .withColumn("new_column",
    when($"old_column".isNull, lit("new_column_true_value"))
      .otherwise($"new_column_false_value"))
  .withColumn("new_column_2",
    when($"old_column_2".isNull, lit("new_column_2_true_value"))
      .otherwise($"new_column_2_false_value"))
```